# Run Azure Functions V3 (.NET 5) on a different port locally

Tags: .net, azure-functions, .net-5, azure-functions-core-tools

With previous versions of Azure Functions, I used to be able to use this line in `Properties -> Debug -> Application Arguments`

```
host start --port 7073 --pause-on-error
```

However, in Azure Functions V3, running .NET 5, it doesn't work.

I get the following message when I try to run it.

> Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
> Possible reasons for this include:
>
> - You misspelled a built-in
>   dotnet command.
> - You intended to execute a .NET program, but
>   dotnet-host does not exist.
> - You intended to run a global tool, but
>   a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the
>   PATH.

Do I need to use a different command for .NET 5? Or put it in a completely different place?

Comment: Did you try VS 2022? The Community discussion on this topic has a suggestion and the final comment says that there is a fix: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cant-debug-multiple-dotnet-5-Azure-Func/1505797

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a little bit of digging with Task Manager and I can see that two dotnet processes run when you start the Function app from VS:

- dotnet path/to/func-sdk/func.dll host start --port 7071 --pause-on-error
- dotnet path/to/your/app/bin/AppName.dll --host 127.0.0.1 --port 51289 --workerId some-guid --requestId some-guid2 --grpcMaxMessage

It seems the command has been changed to `dotnet func.dll host start ...` that is run in the bin/Debug/net5.0 folder, instead of the previous `func host start`.

We are able to change the port at least by setting the Application arguments to:

> "%LOCALAPPDATA%\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\3.23.5\cli_x64\func.dll" host start --port 7073 --pause-on-error

But now we are hard-coding the Functions version :\

I'm not sure if it's possible to get the Functions version/path from variables. If someone knows, do leave a comment :)

Comment: Thank you very much. That is some good digging, although I agree it's an imperfect solution.

Comment: Tried this, but getting a dialog saying "Unable to attach. Process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' is not running on '<computer name>'. Refresh the process list before attempting another attach.

Comment: I have the same issue as @cjk. This solution runs the application, but the VS debugger cannot attach to the process.

Answer (score 3):

For .NET 6 preview with Visual Studio 2022, you can just pass in the following command if it runs as project instead of executable:

```
host start --port 11000
```

For executable project, I have not got it work easily without specifying the detailed paths.
[Build Azure Functions with .NET 6](https://kontext.tech/column/cloud-azure/794/build-azure-functions-with-net-6)

Comment: Good answer but since the question is about .NET 5 I do not mark it as accepted answer.