# Running multiple Azure Functions locally

Tags: azure-functions, visual-studio-2022, azure-functions-core-tools

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2022 with multiple Azure Functions projects in it. The projects are in .NET 4.8 using the v1 of the function run-time.

When debugging locally I want all the function applications to run. I set them all as startup projects in my solution configuration. I had already found that I can change the default port for the function app by setting a command line argument in the debug launch profile, like so.

[image]

The issue is that they all want to bind to port 5858 for debugging. Additional research uncovered the `--nodeDebugPort` argument. I added that to the debug profile but when I run from Visual Studio by hitting F5 they all still want to use 5858. However, if I run them from the command-line using the following command they will honor the debug port setting.

> ..\..\..\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\func host start --port 7072 --nodeDebugPort 5859

Any idea why the debug port argument is ignored when running from Visual Studio but honored when running from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea why the debug port argument is ignored when running from Visual Studio but honored when running from command line?

As suggested by [ahmelsayed](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/313),:

Apart from using `--nodeDebugPort` from command line, you can define it in `local.settings.json`:

```
{
   "NodeDebugPort": 5859
}
```

Other references:  [Two processes of func reusing the same configuration settings](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1414), [How Can I run multiple Azure .net 5 Function Projects locally in Visual Studio 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68737584/how-can-i-run-multiple-azure-net-5-function-projects-locally-in-visual-studio-2) and [How to run Azure Function app on a different port in VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44976890/how-to-run-azure-function-app-on-a-different-port-in-visual-studio)

You can refer to `nodeDebugPort` related issues on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/search?q=nodeDebugPort&type=issues) or open a new issue for further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I have several Azure Functions in my solution and I configure them using `local.settings.json` (per function) by setting the `LocalHttpPort` like below:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    ...
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7073
  }
}
```

And then configure the solution in VS as "Multiple startup pojects" and choose those funcntion apps you wanna run parallel.